# Changing the height of a react-select component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select, jss

I have a relatively straight forward question. When I try to modify the height of a react-select it messes up the position of the internal text. It doesn't appear their styles api lets me dig any deeper into control so I'm not sure how to fix this.

Edit: I'd like to keep the padding.

CodeSandbox: [example of my question](https://codesandbox.io/embed/react-codesandboxer-example-iiiz9?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

[image]

```
import React from "react";
import Select from "react-select";

const customStyles = {
  control: provided => {
    return {
      ...provided,
      width: "100%",
      padding: "10px 12px",
      height: "20px"
    };
  }
};

export default () => <Select styles={customStyles} />;
```

Comment: Is this paading applied to the whole parent element or the inner element of the select?

Comment: Crap, sorry I forgot the code sandbox link. There you can see it.

Answer (score 0):

So you just need to remove the padding and it should be fixed.

Comment: Ideally I'd like to keep the padding. I'm trying to get it to match another component in appearance and to make things easier to maintain I'd rather they both have the same height and padding.

Comment: Then why not just increase the height of it

Comment: I'm confused. Because I'd rather they both have the same height and padding. If the requirements for these ever change it would be easier to update components who's code is the same rather than hacked simply to look the same.

Comment: Can you share the code for the other component ? I mean include both componend in your codeSandbox example

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
import React from "react";
import Select from "react-select";

const customStyles = {
  control: provided => {
    return {
      ...provided,
      width: "100%",
      padding: "0px 12px",
      height: "20px"
    };
  }
};

export default () => <Select styles={customStyles} />;
```